# How to download an excel file in laravel

Tags: laravel, phpexcel

I am trying to download an excel file its working fine but as i have some json columns, so that when i try to include these columns it doesnt work. So far i tried this.

```
public function salarySheetExcel($id)
    {
        $headers = array(
            "Content-type" => "text/csv",
            "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=salary-sheet.csv",
            "Pragma" => "no-cache",
            "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
            "Expires" => "0"
        );

        $salariesOfMonth = SalaryArchive::find($id)->salaries;
        $columns = array('EmployeeCode', 'EmployeeName', 'Weekends','holidays','leaves','absent','present','inform' ,'late','Basic', 'Allowances', 'Allowance Amount',
            'Gross', 'Bonus', 'Overtime Logs', 'Overtime Amount','Net Salary','Deduction Logs','Deduction','PF','Total Salary');

        $callback = function() use ($salariesOfMonth, $columns)
        {
           $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($file, $columns);

            foreach($salariesOfMonth as $salary) {


                $salary=array($salary->employee->employee_code,$salary->attendance_log, $salary->employee->name, $salaries ,
                    $salary->basic,  $salary->allowance_amount,$salary->gross,
                    $salary->bonus,  $salary->overtime_amount,$salary->net_salary,
                    $salary->deduction,$salary->pf,$salary->total_salary);
                fputcsv($file, $salary);
            }
            fclose($file);
        };
        return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
    }
```

**It doesnot work** but when i remove **$salary->attendance_log** its working fine because its my **json** column. Please help me sort it out

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are there any error messages? Is the column just messed up? Simply saying it doesn't work does give us enough information to try and help you.

Comment: if i use json column in the array then the browser says the page you are looking not found

Comment: Check my answer let me know if any issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `json_decode` before add into `fputcsv`.

```
$log = json_decode($salary->attendance_log, true);

$weekends = isset( $log['weekends'] ) ? $log['weekends'] : '';
$holidays =  isset($log['holidays']) ? $log['holidays'] : '';
$leaves   =  isset($log['leaves']) ? $log['leaves'] : '';
$absent   =  isset($log['absent']) ? $log['absent'] : '';
$present  =  isset($log['present'] ? $log['present'] : '';
$inform   =  isset($log['inform']) ? $log['inform'] : '';
$late     =   isset( $log['late'] )? $log['late'] : '';


$salary=array($salary->employee->employee_code, $salary->employee->name, $weekends, $holidays, $leaves, $absent, $present, $inform, $late, $salaries ,
                $salary->basic,  $salary->allowance_amount,$salary->gross,
                $salary->bonus,  $salary->overtime_amount,$salary->net_salary,
                $salary->deduction,$salary->pf,$salary->total_salary);


fputcsv($file, array_merge($salary, $log));
```

Comment: i already tried this , it doesnt work , if i use this i only get 
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:8000/payment/salary-excel/75 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: @TanvirAhmed If you remove `$salary->attendance_log` then working fine right??

Comment: yes and if i json encode it it also work but in excel it comes something like following  but i want to each on separate column {"weekends":4,"holidays":2,"leaves":2,"absent":0,"present":0,"inform":0,"late":0}

Comment: it says json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: @TanvirAhmed Can you try `var_dump($salary->attendance_log)` in controller. Is it return string or object?

Comment: @TanvirAhmed have you used mutators in your salary model? `$casts`

Answer (score 0):

JSON data includes quotes in it's string that's why it's not working.

Use below code.

```
$salary=array($salary->employee->employee_code,addslashes($salary->attendance_log), $salary->employee->name, $salaries ,
                $salary->basic,  $salary->allowance_amount,$salary->gross,
                $salary->bonus,  $salary->overtime_amount,$salary->net_salary,
                $salary->deduction,$salary->pf,$salary->total_salary);
            fputcsv($file, $salary);
```

Comment: it doesnot work it says "addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

Comment: @TanvirAhmed update your code to addslashes(json_encode($salary->attendance_log))

Comment: "weekends\":4,\"holidays\":2,\"leaves\":2,\"absent\":0,\"present\":0,\"inform\":0,\"late\":0}

Comment: it will come like these now